# Triggering external API failes on Timeout

Tags: web-services, netsuite

I am running into a problem with integrating a 3rd-party system into NetSuite.

I am using **nlapiRequestURL** to POST JSON obejct into WebService. This Service is than passing this JSON object into multiple attributes and passes attributes to 3rd-party system. This system is than processing the data and passes a result along with IDs back.

My problem is that the process takes longer than 45 seconds and so the NetSuite throws Timeout exception.

Any ideas how to either increase the timeout limit or workaround?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see any ways to configure timeouts for such function in the docs.

As a workaround you can split your task into two parts. 
1. The first part sends a POST JSON into Web-service and does not wait for response. 
2. For result processing you configure a separate service on NetSuite side (you can write a restlet, for example). The service will be triggered externally to pass IDs back.

Instead of one request, there will be two requests. The first one passes data from NetSuite to 3-rd party system. The second one passes IDs from 3-rd party back to NetSuite.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about the same solution, but requirements were to do this synchronously using single WebService.
Anyway, as long as it seems that there is no other way, I will implement this solution.
Thank you :)